# How to add Company Logo to Chosen Theme

Tags: themes, logo

I have a WordPress Website with the 'Chosen' Theme installed but I am unable to add my Company Logo to it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: This is not a real question, please see [ask] and [help] and learn how to ask a good, real question. Thank you ;-)

Comment: Third party themes are off topic. Maybe you ask support at the correct route, namely [here](https://www.competethemes.com/documentation/chosen-support-center/)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking in the Customiser?

Located here

```
Appearance > Customise > Logo > Select Image (Select your Companies Logo)
```

Best of luck :)

Comment: Sorry, I am making my website using theme chosen , I am unable to add my company logo which I want in left upper corner (in the axis of navigation bar which is at top of the home page). After customizing there are two options in the vertical sidebar in left of the screen one is logo and another header image I uploaded my company logo to the logo option but the image is huge covering the whole page and to upload header image i need plugins.

Comment: I checked many previous questions resembling my issue where people have suggested to do some amendments in coding of header.php link.

Comment: my issue is sort out! thanx all